# Path to image from iOS Gallery Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I was following this tutorial http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/video_and_photos/choose_a_photo_from_the_gallery/ and I can get the path for a video just by doing

```
mediaURL.Path
```

but with an image it returns something like

```
"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=2A456415-B1AE-414A-9795-A0625K768EBD&ext=JPG"
```

and I can not use it to upload to my server because using FileInfo("imageLocaltion") will not find the file.

So with urls like the above how can I access the "real" file path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See "[display image from URL retrieved from ALAsset in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone)" - the same mechanisms apply to Monotouch:

- [MonoTouch: Getting an Image out of ALAssetsLibrary.AssetForUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361425/monotouch-getting-an-image-out-of-alassetslibrary-assetforurl)

Comment: thanks! Using those mechanisms I can now reach the correct filename and a lot more metadata

Comment: I'm still having some troubles in getting the url to use for upload something from the gallery. I can display the photo just fine but where's the real url for the file? All urls are //assets-library/...something ..

Comment: Have you tried to read the file with File.ReadAllBytes() for example?

Comment: yes, it says "Could not find a part of the path" because its adding the path "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=2A4564.." to my app directory path. Using just "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=2A4564.." says that it can't find the file

Comment: any ideas on what to do here?

Comment: I have no idea if it's possible to access a file by it's known path with that protocol, but I guess it's not. Instead take that image out of the library and save it to one of your app's folders. See http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/ for more information.